# postgresql using json sub-element in where clause

Tags: sql, json, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.3

This might be a very basic question but I am not able to find anything on this online.

If I create a sample table :

```
 create table dummy ( id int not null, data json );
```

Then, if I query the table using the following query:

```
select * from dummy where data->'x' = 10;
```

Now since there are no records in the table yet and there is no such property as 'x' in any record, it should return zero results.

But I get the following error:

```
postgres=# select * from dummy where data->'x' = 10;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: json = integer
LINE 1: select * from dummy where data->'x' = 10;
```

However following query works:

```
select * from dummy where cast(data->>'x' as integer) = 10;
```

Am I missing something here or typecasting is the only way I can get an integer value from a json field ? If that's the case, does it not affect the performance when data becomes extremely large ?

Comment: In that case too, the value on the right of the equal sign has to be a string otherwise it gives error. For example   
`postgres=# select * from dummy where data->>'x' = '10';`


`id |   data    
----+-----------
  1 | {"x": 10}
(1 row)`


`postgres=# select * from dummy where data->>'x' = 10;
ERROR:  operator does not exist: text = integer
LINE 1: select * from dummy where data->>'x' = 10;
                                             ^
HINT:  No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.`

Comment: To elaborate what I am trying to say, If I insert another record with id = 10 and perform a self join on the table 

`select * from dummy a, dummy b where a.id = b.data->>'x';`

I still get the same error. Essentially one has to typecast to compare an integer value

Answer (score 21, accepted):

> Am I missing something here or typecasting is the only way I can get
>   an integer value from a json field ?

You're correct, typecasting is the only way to read an integer value from a json field.

> If that's the case, does it not affect the performance when data
>   becomes extremely large ?

Postgres allows you to index functions including casts, so the index below will allow you to quickly retrieve all rows where data->>x has some integer value

```
CREATE INDEX dummy_x_idx ON dummy(cast("data"->>'x' AS int))
```

Answer (score 6):

JSON operator `->>` means [*Get JSON array element (or object field) as text*,](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/functions-json.html) so type cast is necessary.

You could define your own JSON operator, but it would only simplify the code, without consequences for performance.